# Equally vertically spaced button

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

e.g having the same space between them, not resizing them.

For example : top-20dp-button-20dp-button-20dp (20 is an example, I do not want to use dp)

I tried this with no luck :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" android:weightSum="3">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you be more explicit ? I don't really understand what is your question...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the affect your looking for by surrounding each button with it's own linear layout and then setting the weights on the new linear layouts to each be one. From there you just need to tweak the button to specify layout_gravity rather than just gravity (layout_gravity position the view with it's parent, gravity positions elements within the view)

The code would look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is **very** hard to understand, I understand you are not fluent in English but you need to be more specific. Post an image of the design like what you want. I will take another **guess**, maybe this is what you were trying to describe:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Button 3" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I based this off the only description you provided:

> For example : top-20dp-button-20dp-button-20dp

Once again you can use dp, sp, or **anything** that you want; understand that dp stands for density-independent pixel.  Again [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [More Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) describe it very well, you will see that dp is relative. It also describes the difference between dp or dip, which is **not** dpi.

Also notice I changed my padding suggestion to adjusting the margin, I was wrong the first time but with such a vague question it was only a guess. I hope this helps, otherwise  post a clear picture of what you hope to achieve.  Good luck!

Comment: Please read my quesiton again, i do not want to use dp. I want it stay relative.

Comment: Use whatever units you want... But dp is relative,  [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Sam, just the same, 3 butotns are filling all the space in the vertical layout hwen merging your code with mine

Comment: Really ? I thought I was very fluent in english :) OK will try to explain further. I want to have a vertically or horizontally layout thaht fill the screen. In it I want to have 3 buttons, small one. They should fill the space not with their size, but in an harmonious way. For example if you have 3 buttons with 10 dpi size i na screen of 90 dpi : <top>20dpi<button>20dpi<button>20dpi<button>20dpi<bottom>

Comment: 110 dpi for the screen, not only bad in english but in math too :) here's an image : here's an image

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kostya, here's an asnwer :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button 1"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button 2"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button 3"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just have a strange warning from Eclipse (nested weights are bad for performance), why ?